# В чем ошибка подключения к двум БД?

Tags: java, jakarta

Пытаюсь сделать коннект к двум БД.
Проблема на этапе коннекта к MSSQL. При этом, если соединяться только с одной БД проблем нет.
Пробовал разные варианты изменения свойств, но воз и ныне там.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что и как требуется исправить?

application.properties:

```
#db settings
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
#general
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
#spring.jpa.show-sql=true

#words datasource (mysql)
spring.datasource.users.jdbc-url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dr_list
spring.datasource.users.username=fff
spring.datasource.users.password=rrr
spring.datasource.users.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.users.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
server.port = 8083

#contacts datasource (mssql)
spring.datasource.smp.url=jdbc:sqlserver://*****;databaseName=****;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;
spring.datasource.smp.username=ppp
spring.datasource.smp.password=zzz
spring.datasource.smp.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
spring.datasource.smp.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.datasource.smp.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.datasource.smp.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update
spring.datasource.smp.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
spring.datasource.smp.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Config MSSQL:

```
@Configuration
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.example.birthdays.DataBase.smp.Model"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = {"com.example.birthdays.DataBase.smp.Repository"},
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "smpEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "smpTransactionManager")
public class JpaSMPConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.smp")
    public DataSource smpDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean smpEntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            @Qualifier("smpDataSource") DataSource smpDataSource) {
        return builder.dataSource(smpDataSource).packages("com.example.birthdays.DataBase.smp")
                .persistenceUnit("smp").build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public PlatformTransactionManager smpTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("smpEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory smpEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(smpEntityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

Config MySQL:

```
@Configuration
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.example.birthdays.DataBase.Users.Model"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = {"com.example.birthdays.DataBase.Users.Repository"},
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "usersEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "usersTransactionManager")
public class JpaUsersConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.users")
    public DataSource usersDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean usersEntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            @Qualifier("usersDataSource") DataSource usersDataSource) {
        return builder.dataSource(usersDataSource).packages("com.example.birthdays.DataBase.Users")
                .persistenceUnit("Users").build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager usersTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("usersEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory usersEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(usersEntityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

ошибка:

```
Error creating bean with name 'smpEntityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/example/birthdays/configurationDBconnect/JpaSMPConfiguration.class]: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] due to: Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url' for common cases or 'hibernate.dialect' when a custom Dialect implementation must be provided)
```

Comment: Надо писать полный стактрейс в вопрос и указать детали как его воспроизвести. См. [MCVE].